# how to put date picker to a image icon

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have 2 text boxes along with 2 calender image buttons beside them....i want to put some good calander popup to those buttons,,,can any one help me regarding this.... hope you will give a good demo in jsfiddle.. here my code goes.......

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> Start Date : </td>
<td>
<input type="text" size='25' name="dateOfBirth" value=""id="demo1" />
<img src="images/cal.gif"  style="cursor:pointer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td  >End Date :</td>
 <td>
    <input type="text" size='25' name="dateOfBirth" value="" id="demo1" />
    <img src="images/cal.gif"  style="cursor:pointer" />
    </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Date Picker - [Date Picker Example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

This has got many options of restricting date selection of unexpected dates etc.,

To set the format

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yyyy" );
```

Check http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: i have already visited such...not useful for me....i want such date picker to a button,not to text box directly...

Comment: Check the icon trigger in that. When you click on calendar icon, calendar will be opened and the selected date will be set in the text box.

Comment: Demo is already given in the mentioned link - http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: yes but thats coming very largely in my page...can you minimize its dimensions...

Comment: Pl. post your code here or in jsfiddle. I'll try to rectify it.

Comment: its there no in the above question i had mentioned

Comment: in that demo the date was coming into the text box in the format of mm/dd/yyyy but i want the format as dd/mm/yyyy...what should i do now??